# Did she cheat on him?

Tags: mindhunter-2017

In the Netflix show Mindhunter, there is an arc about how Ford gets jealous of a classmate of Debbie's, his girlfriend. Afterward, during a sociology experiment involving a black room, he *"catches"* them together, just sitting kinda intimately. Now, I felt like this was a loose thread and was pretty confused when later in the show they were shown together without resolving this issue.

On the other hand, some people on the Mindhunter subreddit seem pretty convinced that she did cheat on him. Is there some way to establish canon? Something I missed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Now, I felt like this was a loose thread and was pretty confused when later in the show they were shown together without resolving this issue.

It's not clear whether there was erm... *physical intimacy* between Debbie and the classmate but there was certainly "cheating" in some form.

It's clear that there is an attraction between the two and *closeness* [look where his hand is] ... and certainly she doesn't seem to mind the closeness and it looked like she felt *guilt* when they were caught.

[image]

Months later...we see Ford walking past the laundromat and he sees Debbie inside.

[image]

The interaction between the two indicates, at least to me, that *even if she did cheat* he elected to forgive her and rekindle the relationship.

So the "resolution" was unspoken and, for the most part, unseen but that's not to say it won't come up again in Season 2.